# UIScrollView with image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Is it possible to use a UIScrollView to see an image that is about 800px long? I tried using a UIScrollView and the UIImageView but it's not scrolling. Anybody can help please?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
UIScrollView *yourScrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0,0}, {320,480}}];

UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageHere.png"]];
yourImageView.frame = yourScrollview.bounds;

yourScrollview.contentSize = yourImageView.frame.size;
yourScrollview.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
yourScrollview.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
[yourScrollview setZoomScale:yourScrollview.minimumZoomScale];
yourScrollview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:yourScrollview];
```

Don't forget to add UIScrollViewDelegate in your .h file

Note: ARC code

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a new Project -> Single View Application 

2. Put the follow code into:**

## "ViewController.m"

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; 
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

    UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)]; 
    UIImageView * myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage : [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"]];
    [myView addSubview: myImage];
    [myImage release];
    [scrollView addSubview: myView];
    [myView release];

    [self.view addSubview: scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

**3. Put the Image "Test.png" into your Project (Drag Drop into Xcode -> Folder:Supporting Files)**

Answer (score 0):

If it is not panning it means you forgot to set the `contentSize` property. I have a tutorial on my website that shows how to embed a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` and set it up for both panning and zooming. It includes complete downloadable source code. See [Panning and Zooming with UIScrollView](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/07/07/tutorial-all-about-images-part-2-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/)

Answer (score -1):

```
@interface ZoomViewController : UIViewController <uiscrollviewdelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
    UIImageView *image;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scroll;

@end
</uiscrollviewdelegate></uikit>
```

Once check your Viewdidload method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

       image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_body.png"]];

        [super viewDidLoad];

    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_body.png"]];

    scroll.contentSize = image.frame.size;

    [scroll addSubview:image];

    scroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;

    scroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;

    scroll.delegate = self;
    [scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: Thank you but i keep on getting an error on this page:
image =[[UIImage View alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];

Comment: there shouldnt be a space: [UIImage View alloc] should say [UIImageView alloc]